# Which currency rounding algorithm to use in .Net?

Tags: c#, sql-server, currency

Is there a best practice on which rounding algorithm to use in .Net for decimal currency rounding operations that takes into account back-end systems? Real world experience appreciated.

---

.Net uses Banker’s Rounding by default.  (**MidpointRounding.ToEven**) This is at odds with the SQL Server back-end that I’ll be using because SQL Server uses arithmetic rounding (**MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero**) and has no built in function to mimic Banker's Rounding.

Note: I'm using decimal(18, 4) in SQL Server, decimal in .Net

Here's an example of .Net's default Banker's Rounding to two decimal places vs. SQL Server's rounding to two decimal places:

```
| Value | .Net  | SQL Server  |
|-------|-------|-------------|
| 2.445 | 2.44  | 2.45        |
| 2.455 | 2.46  | 2.46        |
| 2.465 | 2.46  | 2.47        |
| 3.445 | 3.44  | 3.45        |
| 3.455 | 3.46  | 3.46        |
| 3.465 | 3.46  | 3.47        |

// t-sql
declare @decimalPlaces int
set @decimalPlaces = 2

select round(convert(decimal(18, 4), 2.445), @decimalPlaces) -- 2.45
select round(convert(decimal(18, 4), 2.455), @decimalPlaces) -- 2.46
select round(convert(decimal(18, 4), 2.465), @decimalPlaces) -- 2.47
select round(convert(decimal(18, 4), 3.445), @decimalPlaces) -- 3.45
select round(convert(decimal(18, 4), 3.455), @decimalPlaces) -- 3.46
select round(convert(decimal(18, 4), 3.465), @decimalPlaces) -- 3.47

// .Net
var algorithm = MidpointRounding.ToEven;
var decimalPlaces = 2;
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(2.445M, decimalPlaces, algorithm).ToString()); // 2.44
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(2.455M, decimalPlaces, algorithm).ToString()); // 2.46
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(2.465M, decimalPlaces, algorithm).ToString()); // 2.46
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(3.445M, decimalPlaces, algorithm).ToString()); // 3.44
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(3.455M, decimalPlaces, algorithm).ToString()); // 3.46
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(3.465M, decimalPlaces, algorithm).ToString()); // 3.46
```

If I ever retrieve a value from SQL Server and let it handle the rounding I'll wind up with pennies off here and there as compared to what .Net were to tell me because of it's default Banker's Rounding.

It seems that I should forge ahead and use arithmetic rounding throughout my .Net code base but I see an open source project ([nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/downloads.aspx)) using the default Banker's Rounding so it makes me wonder what the best approach is.

---

Perhaps a better question is: Is there any reason **not** to use arithmetic rounding (**MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero**) for currencies in .Net?

Comment: Only per use case, if you are converting unit of measures they need to specify the kind of rounding, if you are doing monetary operations you shouldn't round off.

Comment: If you are worried about pennies then why are you rounding 2.44?   Best practice is to NOT round if it is going to introduce inaccuracies or inconsistencies.  Memory is cheap - why are you rounding at all?

Comment: @Blam you can have more than 2dp when working with currency values. Some businesses work with e.g. very small items they sell in bulk and keep the individual price at, say, 4dp - for example 0.0135 for a screw. You obviously can't pay 0.35 of a penny but it does add up when you sell 50,000 of them. And then in the total you might want to round it up to 2dp for a "realistic" representation

Comment: @Boris Rounding an output and rounding data is not the same thing.  Just how would rounding the actual cost from 0.0135 solve anything?  How would rounding a cost value stored in SQL solve anything?

Comment: @Blam I think the main reasons for rounding are actually on the business side, not technical ones (e.g. memory restrictions) and often agreed on with the client to match their process. So the question usually isn't whether to round at all but how to do it consistently, as the OP is asking.

Comment: @Boris But that is not that stated (or at least implied) question.  At odds with SQL has nothing to do with it.  You store the full precision in SQL or not - it is a simple as that.  With cost of memory and hard disc today there is no reason not store the full precision is SQL.  OP is mixing storage precision with calculation precision.  "Forge ahead".   You forge ahead with full data precision and no rounding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0#midpoint-values-and-rounding-conventions):

> Rounding away from zero is the most widely known form of rounding, while rounding to nearest even is the standard in financial and statistical operations. It conforms to IEEE Standard 754, section 4. When used in multiple rounding operations, rounding to nearest even reduces the rounding error that is caused by consistently rounding midpoint values in a single direction. In some cases, this rounding error can be significant.

Banker's rounding *rarely* makes sense in the real world. I used to work in the banking industry and they once sent me on a mission to stamp out "rounding errors" in reports that were due to this culprit.

In addition to banking, calculating shipping, income tax, and sales tax always uses "away from zero" rounding.

The only real world use I can think of for banker's rounding is for perhaps calculating interest and splitting the difference or perhaps paying out commissions.

Microsoft did not choose to make the default `MidpointRounding.ToEven` for good reason. They did so to maintain backward compatibility with Visual Basic (prior to .NET). It was not done so because it is a reasonable default, or best default of any kind. If they had to make the decision again today, it would most likely be `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`.

Keep in mind, when someone checks your work they will be using the "away from zero" method that we all learned in grade school. In my opinion, "because Microsoft made it the default" is not a good enough excuse for the program to be using it. There should be a valid business reason to use banker's rounding if and when it is necessary. If it is not explicitly called out in the application requirements, you should use `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`. It works best to *change* the default in your application framework to `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm thinking too but there are a lot of people saying the exact opposite. argh.. Considering this comes from real world experience I'm still leaning towards this as the correct answer.

Comment: I found some documentation out there from real businesses that also echo the same rule of using `AwayFromZero` rounding: (difficult to find this stuff) [xencraft](http://www.xencraft.com/resources/multi-currency.html#rounding), [zuora](https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/CB_Billing/TB_Rounding_and_Precision) It appears that different currencies have different rules but since I'm only dealing with USD currency at the moment it doesn't matter.

Comment: another from stackexchange echoing the same thing for USD: [Sales Tax: Rounded Then Totaled or Totaled Then Rounded?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15051/sales-tax-rounded-then-totaled-or-totaled-then-rounded)

Answer (score 3):

When you truly need to round, do so in *Only* one environment. Failing to do so will cause you to rely on defaults and configurations which will eventually bite you. All other places keep the precision you were handed to avoid any strange issues.

Which algorithm you use is Dependant on the use case for your application. But regardless, pick one and make sure you have it centralized and changeable as needed.

Also the. Net default is the most common rounding for money values, so unless you have a sound, business reason to not use it, I would stick with that. The uneven distribution can otherwise cause real monetary consequences over time.

Comment: So the same comment I gave to @Boris applies here. If another application is responsible for reporting you may not have a choice but to use the back-end system's rounding function. With time all architectures erode and putting a rule in place like, only do rounding in .Net, will eventually be forgotten, not enforced over time. Do you have a reference to your last statement about uneven distributions becoming a problem over time? If I consistently apply a specific rounding algorithm why would it become a problem some time in the future?

Comment: Saying that an architectural rule will eventually broken so not to use them is like saying a law will eventually be broken and thus should not be bothered with. It's defeatist, and a silly attitude. The uneven distribution is with reference to how the results are distributed. Because of how they round, you may end up with an overall trend that is different than the underlying data and thus shorts you, our whoever you are paying which can become significant over time.  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Comment: there is no "silly attitude" in my comment, please don't do personal attacks. Sorry, but [software erosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture#Software_architecture_erosion) is real and I've seen it happen repeatedly for the past 18 years. The point of this post is to figure out how make it a moot point by having both .Net and SQL Server respond with the same rounding results so regardless of how many applications or reporting tools are using the same data source they are all able to round numbers identically and there are no discrepancies to resolve in the first place.

Comment: And when the newest version of your platform changes defaults breaking your whole application because it now rounds two different ways? I never personally attacked you. I stand but what I said. Maintaining architecture isn't easy. It takes effort, and dedication. It takes constantly watching for deviations. But to avoid doing so is a recipe for a mess. Building codes exist to ensure that there are consistent, quality buildings. Architecture rules exist for the same reason. You asked for best practices, and here they are: never rely on platform defaults for important application behaviors.

Answer (score 3):

Use `decimal` rather than `float / double` because floats and doubles need to be stored in base 2, and decimal gets stored in base 10. If you map your SQL Server type to `decimal` in .NET your rounding issues will go away.

RE: the algorithm, dealing with monetary values, you have to either

- Make sure you store enough decimal places in each value/calculation step as to make sure any rounding errors are so small that they can be dismissed
- Use bankers rounding, to try and mitigate rounding errors

Imagine the following:

```
        Real Value  Standard    Bankers
        0.25        0.3         0.2
        0.75        0.8         0.8
-----------------------------------------
Sum     1           1.1         1
```

Basically, using bankers rounding, whenever you have a

```
x.5  (e.g. 6.5)
```

Using standard rounding, you will always round up, meaning for every midpoint rounding, you are adding 0.5 to the total value, but using bankers rounding, when `x` is even, you round down (-0.5) and when `x` is odd, you round up (+0.5) so there is a higher chance that with random values, the `+0.5` and `-0.5` cancel each other out.

Ofcourse, if you can store each value with a large enough percision, these rounding error are so miniscule they can be discarded.

Personally for calculations I always use Bankers, but for display to UI I use AwayFromZero (as its more natural)

Comment: In no way does this answer the question.

Comment: The root of his problem is the fact he is using a `float/double` to represent a base 10 value in base 2. Rounding base 2 numbers is different to rounding base 10 numbers. No matter what algo you use to round, if you are rounding in base 2, and displaying in base 10, you can never be sure you will get the right results.

Comment: Hence rounding 2.45 as decimal, with (MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) will be round to 2.5 (which is what in most currency cases I expect. Where as rounding the same number `(float)2.45` using `AwayFromZero` will round it to 2.4. Why? because float is in base 2, and the way the number is stored, it is not 2.5, its < 2.45 which causes the rounding to be off.

Comment: Once you get rid of base 2 rounding errors, only then can you start thinking about the rounding algorithm.

Comment: I am using decimal in .Net and in SQL Server. I have no clue why your saying I'm using a double or a float.

Comment: What you call 'standard rounding' is no longer 'standard'.  Round to even, which you call "'banker's rounding" is now pretty standard, and is used by Python.  `round(.25, 1) == .2`.

Comment: I don't know what country you live in, or what school you went to, but in UK standard rounding is away from zero. Just because certain languages decide to implement it otherwise, does not mean it is "Standard" to me, Standard means what the world thinks of rounding, not what a programming language(s) use as rounding.

Comment: The only reason I can think of that bankers rounding was used was to minimize rounding errors in calculations, when there wasn't any data structure to minimize these errors.

Comment: @MichalCiechan, based on your final statement, if you calculate that a purchase is 24.9450 and charge the customer $24.94, based on banker's rounding, yet display that you charged them $24.95, based on arithmetic rounding (away from zero), how is that not causing you a world of grief from the customer and/or the people viewing the financial reports?

Comment: Why would you be charging them 24.9450? I would do all of the calculations sum(price * quantity), using bankers rounding. then if it is something that needs to be rounded to 2dp, I store it rounded. Therefore charging the customer whatever rounded value I use, and then displaying it in AwayFromZero if they so wish

Comment: I either charge the customer 24.945 or round the value, and store the rounding, and display the rounding. If I charge the customer 24.945, and they wish to see 2dp, they accept the grief. I have this argument all the time. Especially, they when you have 3 values (0.3,0.3,0.3) round all using any rounding, give you (0,0,0) yet the sum rounding is 1. Its grief that the user accepts when they choose to round to certain amount of dp

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen where I work, our practice is to keep everything default for both .NET and SQL Server - which makes things more maintainable. However this means you need to ensure that rounding is consistently done throughout your system, as Tim pointed.

What we do is, we ensure all numbers are rounded by the application itself, be it single prices (which might be e.g. 4dp sometimes) or totals (which are usually 2dp), calling Math.Round with the appropriate value for the number of decimal digits. SQL Server then just stores what it receives (using a decimal(18,4) usually).

You can then add an extra layer of consistency on your user interface, it might depend on what controls you're using but you could for example restrict a number field to the appropriate number of digits, so the user doesn't type e.g. 1.32682 if your application is only going to save 1.33.

Comment: But what happens when you're application is not responsible for reporting. Lets say Crystal Reports are used to show financials to the big wigs. It's going to round using SQL Server's function. Whatever rules I build into the .Net application are null and void. And what if some director wants to account for the discrepancy he sees between his crystal report and what my application says?

Comment: @TugboatCaptain Why would categorize the .NET application as null and void because Crystal Reports did it differently?  You do the correct calculation.  Really you would chase what you consider an incorrect calculation to be consistent with an incorrect report?

Comment: @Blam, based on your comments thus far you're clearly missing the point. Please let me how a crystal report is supposed to do Banker's Rounding when it rely's on SQL Server's rounding function which is arithmetic based and we can go from there.

Comment: @TugboatCaptain, good point on the external reporting, not sure I can think of a way to avoid the discrepancy without changing either algorithm. I'm wondering though: if you're doing a certain calculation on both the report and in the application, is this not a duplication of effort? I'd say either leave all the calculations in the system logic and only store the final result in the DB for the report to show, or let the report handle all the logic and don't do the same in code.

Comment: @TugboatCaptain I am not missing the point.  Tug you are missing the boat.  Crystal is either right or wrong - you decide.  If you feel it is wrong and you are chasing it for consistency then that is your decision.  Really you think some big wig even wants to see pennies?

Comment: @Blam, when reading and understanding the question is of little significance, when the pursuit of knowledge no longer concerns you, when architecture and doing things right the first time no longer has meaning to you, when the thought of potentially losing your company’s money, no not just that, your own money no longer matters, you find yourself here desperately pleading to make a statement about nothing.

Comment: @TugboatCaptain And here you are desperately pleading to make a statement about nothing.  A Crystal Report to big wigs with out without a rounding error they don't even care about is NOT real money.  If you chose to make functional calculations to match a report you think is wrong then that is your problem.  This is not a technical issue.  Man up and put out the number you trust or match a number a number you don't trust.