# Decimal default rounding mode and currency formatting

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding, currency, bankers-rounding

Consider the following code:

```cs
decimal value = 12.345m;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C"));
```

> £12.35

Given that the default `MidpointRounding` mode in .NET is `MidpointRounding.ToEven`, why does this value round up (away from an even number, which would be 12.34) when formatting as currency?

For reference:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(value, 2));
```

> 12.34

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which currency rounding algorithm to use in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185850/which-currency-rounding-algorithm-to-use-in-net)

Comment: Rounding away from zero is the most widely known form of rounding, while rounding to nearest even is the **standard in financial and statistical operations**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The special [currency format specifier `C`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#currency-format-specifier-c) will round away from zero when rounding the decimal places:

> If the value to the right of the number of specified decimal places is 5 or greater, the last digit in the result string is rounded away from zero.

You have the fraction digits `.345` and the `CurrencyDecimalDigits` property is set to `2` (in this situation). This means that "right of the number of specified decimal places" is `5`, and that is greater or equal to `5`. The documentation states that in this case, the value `12.345` is rounded up, away from zero, to `12.35`.